# Is there any way to add weapons to a Fighter's Weapon Group

Tags: pathfinder-1e, weapons, fighter

The Brawler hybrid class is proficient with all weapons in the "Close" Fighter Weapon Group, and can use multiple abilities, such as increasing the damage of these weapons, or using these weapons as part of a Flurry.

Is there any way to add additional weapons to this group, using only official Paizo material?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes, kind of.**

Specifically, you can make any melee weapon part of the Close Weapon Group with the [Weapon Modification](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/weapon-modifications/) called [Versatile Design](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/weapon-modifications/versatile-design/) for 500g (mundane) or 750g (magically Enhanced).

> When versatile design is added to a weapon, choose a fighter weapon group. The modified weapon is considered to be a weapon of that weapon group (such as for the fighter’s weapon training class feature).

Use with the Brawler's class features would be up to the GM, so check before you invest. However, it should work.

Note: Any weapon modification increases the 'difficulty' of the weapon by one- Simple becomes Martial, Martial becomes Exotic, and Exotic becomes impossible to wield properly. Furthermore, specific weapon proficiency (IE Rogues have proficiency with Rapiers) no longer applies. The [Modified Weapon Proficiency](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/modified-weapon-proficiency-combat/) and [Weapon Adept](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/weapon-adept-combat/) feats (as well as Martial/Exotic Proficiency, where applicable) allow you to bypass this if it would cause problems with your ability to wield your weapon of choice.

Comment: That's great, but how does this work with Brawler proficiencies?  IE: I want to use a Light Hammer, which I don't have proficiency with.  By modifying it to close, will I be able to use it with/without Weapon Adept? Or will I need Matial Prof and Modified Prof feat?

Comment: You'll have to check with your GM on how they want to adjudicate. As written, the Modification would give you proficiency with the weapon, so you would only need the Weapon Adept (Versatile Design) feat. Note that you don't qualify for the MW Prof feat, but that doesn't affect your use case. That being said, a GM could absolutely say that the Versatile Design doesn't affect proficiency because it's written vaguely. So we come back around.

Comment: If it helps, stylize it as light hammer 'fists'... such as knuckles that have a small hammer sticking from them or something like that.